# Resizing the background svg

Tags: css, html, svg

I want to resize the local svg using in background-image, but setting the width=100% and height=100% not working.
I've even resized the svg image into 1425pixels x 835pixels

[image: This is the output when using svg image as background]

my css code: -

```
#main-page #products-section {
text-align: center;
background-image: url('/assets/images/product_background_img.svg');
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

when using `background-image: url('/assets/images/product_background_img.png');`

The Output is: [image: This is the output when using png image as background]

It's working fine with .png Image, but I want to achieve same with svg file. Since png images are of greater file size, and it'll create my web-page heavy.

Comment: does  product_background_img.svg have a viewBox, if not, give it one.

Comment: how to give this, since I've exported this image as svg after creating in figma.

Comment: What is the width of the element you assign the background image to? It might be that it doesn't reach the whole screen, so maybe try and increase that size

Comment: It's 100%, though If I'm increasing the width, it's floating right side, but not increasing the width of svg image

Comment: Please post your SVG.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1oC3y5hb6ir9J8ERFBQnDN4deFmt4DxVx

here you can find it, I'm not able to upload here, since it's svg file

Answer (score 1):

You could try `height: 100vh` and `width: 100vw` instead of `height: 100%` and `width: 100%`.

Comment: I tried this, but this is increasing only the height, width remains same.

Comment: change: background-size: contain;

Comment: It's floating the background image to left side, and approx 30% of width from right side of screen is transparent, it should fill whole div element, but not working.

Answer (score -1):

try,

```
background-size: auto|length|cover|contain|initial|inherit;
```